# Number of subsets of size 'k' whose sum when taken mod with 'p' gives 'x'

Tags: algorithm

Given: a set of size n with integer elements in range [1,p] and an integer k<=n

suppose function

```
f(a subset) = (sum of all elements in the subset)%p
```

I need to find for each x such that `0<=x<=p-1` how many subsets of size k will have

```
f( the subset ) = x
```

A dp solution with complexity n*p*k is trivial but is there a n*p solution?

Comment: Are the numbers always `[1,p]` or are they some given set of numbers? If they are always that certain range of numbers, aren't `p` and `n` the same number?

Comment: Can't think of any :(

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov u can assume that not all elements are distinct in the set.